# Extract user details from ad network - Champcash like application

Tags: android, admob, mobile-application

Im building a champcash like application in which the user get reward on downloading apps.
In addition to that , the sponsor who invited the user also gets 10% of the reward which user achieved.

Since the *ADMOB, ADXMI, Super Sonic* etc ad networks won't support these features, ad network just pay money to admin and we need to create some methods to calculate how much earning admin have and we need to do the calculation to give some amount to user and sponsor. The problem is, i cannot get the **detail of the user who downloaded** the app, thus cant do the calculation.

I need to know how can i extract the user details from the ad network !